# Add multiple model statistics with add_glance_table() horizontaly (and not verticaly) in tbl_regression

Tags: r, gtsummary, concordance-index

I used tbl_regression and add_glance_table() from `gtsummary` to build a table with model statistic:

```
library(gtsumary)
coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ score, data = dat) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  add_glance_table(concordance)
```

1st question: **How can I move the model statistic horizontaly, to the right?**

[image: cox]

Because, in the end, I want to display multiple model statistic, with C index in the last column, like this:

```
tbl_uvregression(
  dat_score,
  method=survival::coxph,
  y = Surv(time, event),
  exponentiate = TRUE)
```

[image: cox2]

2nd question: **How do I add `add_glance_table` in `tbl_uvregression`?**

Answer (score 3):

You can merge any additional columns/statistics into a gtsummary using the `modify_table_body()` function (the `table_body` is an internal data frame that is styled and printed as the summary table).

It's possible to add the c-index in a `tbl_uvregression()` setting. But I think it requires a higher understanding of the internals of a `tbl_uvregression()` object. In the example below, I estimate each univariable model separately, summarize the model with `tbl_regression()`, merge in the c-index, then stack all the tbls with `tbl_stack()`.

Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

covariates <- c("age", "marker")

# iterate over the covariates
tbl <-
  covariates %>%
  map(
    function(varname) {
      # build regression model
      mod <- 
        str_glue("Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ {varname}") %>%
        as.formula() %>%
        coxph(data = trial)
      # calculate and format c-index. adding variable column to merge in the next step
      df_cindex <- 
        broom::glance(mod) %>% 
        select(concordance) %>% 
        mutate(
          concordance = style_sigfig(concordance, digits = 3),
          variable = varname
        )
      
      # summarize model
      tbl_regression(mod, exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
        # merge in the c-index
        modify_table_body(~left_join(.x, df_cindex, by = "variable")) %>%
        modify_header(concordance = "**c-index**") # assigning a header label unhides the column
    }
  ) %>%
  #stack all tbls
  tbl_stack()
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Daniel but I hopped for a maybe simplier solution... what do you mean by "it's possible to add the c-index in a tbl_uvregression() setting. But I think it requires a higher understanding of the internals of a tbl_uvregression() object?" By running your code, i got this error: ```Error in select(., concordance) : unused argument (concordance)```

Comment: This code was run in a proper reprex, fresh R environment. I suggest you ensure you have all the packages installed/updated, and try again.

Comment: Great answer. Can also be used for other statistics (r2, AIC, etc). May want to include  `modify_table_body(~mutate(.x, concordance = if_else(header_row %in% FALSE, NA_character_, concordance)))` to remove repetition over multiple rows if you have a factor covariate (e.g. 'stage' in this example).